# ReactVR global key press event listener

Tags: events, input, keyboard, react-360

How, in ReactVR app, can I detect when user click some specific key? I have a function for catching this event but when I put it on `View` component like this `<View onInput={(e) => this.handleInput(e)}>` it catch it only when I have my cursor on some component inside this view and I want to know this regardless of user cursor position or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out? I also want to do something similar.

For now I made a giant invisible `<View`> immediately in front of the camera, and used `onInput` there. I'll see if I can find a better solution, but for now that's what I am doing.

Edit: Some more progress (not sure how far you got)

```
handle(e) { 
  console.log('Event', e.nativeEvent.inputEvent)
}

<View 
  onInput={e => this.handle(e)}
  style={{
    transform: [{translate: [0, 0, -1]}],
    layoutOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
  }}
</View>
```

My `View` is small, but you can play with the `style`.

The docs said I can use `event.type`, but that didn't work for me. I read about `nativeEvent` in [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/112).

You can see many properties, like:

- type
- key (for Keyboard event)
- viewportX and viewportY (for mouse event)

and so on.

The docs are not that in depth. I recommend reading Github issues a lot. Hopefully the docs and ecosystem will grow more soon. For now the best option is Stackoverflow, and spreading the knowledge we have figure out.